# How can I create multiple output files within a while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, math

I have managed to write a file with some data inside it. However, no matter what I do I can only get one output file for the final iteration of the code when I would like different output files with different names per iteration of the while loop (which changes the initial condition of S0):

```
# zombie apocalypse modeling
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import pandas as pd
plt.ion()
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 10, 8

P = 0      # birth rate
d = 0.0001  # natural death percent (per day)
B = 0.0095  # transmission percent  (per day)
G = 0.0001  # resurect percent (per day)
A = 0.0001  # destroy percent  (per day)

# solve the system dy/dt = f(y, t)
def f(y, t):
     Si = y[0]
     Zi = y[1]
     Ri = y[2]
     # the model equations (see Munz et al. 2009)
     f0 = P - B*Si*Zi - d*Si
     f1 = B*Si*Zi + G*Ri - A*Si*Zi
     f2 = d*Si + A*Si*Zi - G*Ri
     return [f0, f1, f2]

# initial conditions
S0 = 500.              # initial population
Z0 = 0                 # initial zombie population
R0 = 0                 # initial death population

while S0 < 600
    S0 += 5

    y0 = [S0, Z0, R0]     # initial condition vector
    t  = np.linspace(0, 5., 1000)         # time grid

    # solve the DEs
    soln = odeint(f, y0, t)
    S = soln[:, 0]
    Z = soln[:, 1]
    R = soln[:, 2]

df = pd.dataframes({S,Z,R]} 
df.to_csv('test.txt', sep='\t')
```

How can this be done?

Comment: You are using the to_csv function only once. Why do you expect multiple files to be written?

Comment: I initially placed the function within the loop thinking it would produce multiples files, but it did not.

Comment: That probably was because you were using the same filename each time.

Comment: Yes, using the advice given, I added a counter to the while loop and implemented the counter in the file name. Works as intended now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os

for k in range(1,10):

    # some loop

    with open("myfile.{}.csv".format(k), "w") as f:  # put a counter inside the files name
        f.write("some data") 
print( os.listdir("./"))
```

Output:

```
['myfile.8.csv', 'myfile.7.csv', 'myfile.6.csv', 'myfile.4.csv',
 'myfile.5.csv', 'main.py', 'myfile.9.csv', 'myfile.1.csv', 
 'myfile.2.csv', 'myfile.3.csv']
```

---

Our you could just find out if the file exists and then increment it automagically:

```
import os
import datetime


def newName(baseName):
    """Checks if baseName exists, if not inserts a running 
    counter and increments it until file does not exist."""

    n = baseName[:-4]+".{}"+baseName[-4:]  # assumes a len-3 filenameextension like txt
    if not os.path.exists(baseName):
        return baseName

    i = 0
    while os.path.exists( n.format(i)):
        i+=1

    return n.format(i)


with open(newName("myfile.csv"),"w") as f: # newName checks and creates a unique name
    f.write("some data") 

with open(newName("myfile.csv"),"w") as f: # if the file already exists.
    f.write("some data") 

with open(newName("myfile.csv"),"w")  as f:
    f.write("some data") 

print( os.listdir("./"))
```

Output:

```
['myfile.1.csv', 'myfile.csv', 'myfile.0.csv', 'main.py']
```

Comment: Thank you for this, is the process similar for pandas.Dataframe? That is what I have used to structure my data in a tabular fashion

Comment: @jipes your dataframe takes the name of the file as string. You can do the same thing:  `df.to_csv('test{}.txt'.format(mycounter}, sep='\t')` and `mycounter` is a numeric variable that you increase on each while. Or you use  `df.to_csv(newName('test.txt'), sep='\t')  `   function to check if the file exists and if, autoinsert an incrementing number. You could also inserte a timestamp - depending on the amount of time that passes you could get away with a hh:mm:ss or smth else. Endless possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Create a counter within the while loop and increment it each iteration that you want the output file to change. 
The choose the file to use based on the counter value.